# Issues creating Muxed Account - dotnet-stellar-sdk

Tags: stellar-sdk, c#-sdk, dotnet-sdk

I hope this is the best place to find answers to this issue. I have attempted many times to create muxed accounts using this SDK (dotnet-stellar-sdk), but I continue to have this problem where any Muxed accounts that are created do not get created in stellar or become associated with the base account (G… Address). So once I make a muxed account and try to look for it in stellar expert or stellar lab, it won't come up, or it comes up with a different base account address.

I also tried to do this with the JS SDK for testing purposes, and it works as intended. However, I am just lost, and I do not want to keep trying if I do it incorrectly. So please help me find a solution to this problem. Thank you. Please see the images below, which might explain this better.

Also, I am newer to working with Stellar so if I am going about this the wrong way I would really appreciate any pointers. I tried looking everywhere for answers but cant seem to find any documentation on creating the Muxed Account with dotnet-stellar-sdk.

---JS Attempt
[image: JSAttempt]

[image]

-- dotnet Issues
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try with the exact same account in JS and .NET?

Comment: Yes it was an issue with the dotnet-stellar-sdk they are currently working on fixing it. Thank you though!